# Installing fastcgi so

Tags: apache-http-server, fastcgi

Following the install instructions I start with:

```
apxs -o mod_fastcgi.so -c *.c
```

which produces .o, .la, .lo, .slo but no .so, so the next step of:

```
apxs -i -a -n fastcgi mod_fastcgi.so
```

fails.

I tried the more manual approach of moving Makefile.AP2 to Makefile and running

```
make top_dir=/path/to/http
```

Which complains about a missing "special.mk" if you set it incorrectly, so with it set correctly that works and on the next step of

```
make install
```

it complains that top_dir is a Directory.  Of course it's a directory!

???  Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/humanmade/hm-dev/wiki/Setup-a-local-dev-environment-on-Mac-OSX-Lion

Comment: What OS/Distro?

Answer (score 2):

If you have OS X, try:

```
top_dir=/usr/share/httpd
```

… and add one line:

```
CFLAGS=-arch x86_64
```

This might work.